# LaTeX listings package: different style for constants/classes/variables

Tags: latex, package, tex, listings

I'm using the `listings` package for syntax highlighting, set up with the following arguments:

```
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  captionpos=b,
  tabsize=3,
  frame=lines,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{red}
}
```

This works fairly well, resulting in:

[image: (screenshot 1 of resulting document)]
[image: (screenshot 2 of resulting document)]

What I would like, is that the constants `MIN_PIXELS` and `MAX_PROCESSING_TIME` are styled in a different color, and the class names `Rectangle`, `Bitmap`, etc. are styled in yet another color. It would also be nice if I could get numbers colored, but that's not my main focus.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation of listings (page 20ff.): `\lstset{morecomment=[s][\color{blue}]{/*+}{*/},
        morecomment=[s][\color{red}]{/*-}{*/}}`
You can try to set `morekeywords` and give a specific keyword the right color.

Comment: Great suggestion, I'll give it a swing. I would prefer a method based upon regular expressions, if that is at all possible, because otherwise I'd need to specify all class names and constants in `lstset`.

Comment: This works! I was able to highlight specific keywords; e.g. for `MIN_PIXELS` I used: `morecomment=[s][\color{darkblue}]{MIN_PIXELS}{\ }`

Answer (score 4):

Listings only works by keywords, so it is not possible.

[**Minted**](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) uses a python library (Pygments) and can do any kind of highlighting as it is able to understand the code and not just keywords.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was looking for a solution specifically for `listings`, but I'll consider `minted` in the future.

Comment: I was annoyed by some other problems with `listings`, so I, too, have switched to `minted`. It was a pain to install, but it is definitely worth it!